# Magento 2.0 extensions/plugins compatibility

Tags: magento2, extensions, upgrade, plugin

We are planning to upgrade one of the Magento store to version 2.0, and during the first phase, were checking the compatibility of version 2.0 with following extensions/plugin which store is using. Can anyone please tell me if these are compatible? or if there is any alternate way of using them in Magento 2.0

AOE Scheduler --- Not Found

Brainvire - OrderComment --- Not Found

PRESELECT COLORS PLUS SWATCHES - 3.5.4 --- Not Found

Cm_RedisSession --- Not Found

Creare_Exportdownloads --- Not Found

Dotdigitalgroup_Email --- Not Found

Dotdigitalgroup_Mailcheck --- Not Found

Dotsquares_Taxrate --- Not Found

Fix_FixBlockCacheInvalidated --- Not Found

Flagbit_ChangeAttributeSet --- Not Found

Mass 301 Redirects - Optimise Web --- Not Found

OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts  ---  Not Found

Payserv_GoogleFinance  ---  Not Found

Phoenix_Moneybookers  ---  Not Found

Phoenix_VarnishCache  ---  Not Found

Spranks_RefreshBlockHtmlCache  ---  Not Found

ThinkEgyptian_Gridthumbs  ---  Not Found

Wee_Base  ---  Not Found

Grid Actions  ---  Not Found

XtCore  ---  Not Found

Thanks,
Farmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1 extensions aren't compatible like in "Just install the 1.x version and you're done". The developers of the extensions need to build an entirely new extension for Magento 2.

A lot of Magento 1 extensions haven't been developed for Magento 2 yet, so for now you can wait for the extensions to be developed for Magento 2, develop them yourself (based on your list of extensions, that will be a lot of work) or check if alternatives are available.